# writing a specific string to a file with Java

Tags: java

my codes dont seem to properly address what i intend to achieve.

- a long string instead of a well broken and seperated string
- it does not handle the 'seperator' appropriately ( produces , instead of ",")
- also the 'optional' ( produces ' instead of " '")

Current result:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'max.csv'BADFILE 'max.bad'DISCARDFILE 
'max.dis' APPEND INTO TABLEADDRESSfields terminated by,optionally enclosed  
 by'(ID,Name,sex)
```

the intended result should look like this

is there a better way of doing this or improving the above codes

Comment: Personally, I'd use a templating mechanism. That aside, why *would* it look like what you're showing? You don't add any spaces or newlines.

Comment: Just to make sure you're aware of it, adding writing your string on multiple lines in your code doesn't mean it will be on multiple lines when you write it to the file. If you want to have a return somewhere in there you have to add the endline character, it's usually \n but to be sure you can use System.getProperty("line.separator");

Answer (score 2):

Yeah. Use the character `\n` to start a new line in the file, and escape `"` characters as `\"`. Also, you'll want to add a space after each variable.

```
content = " LOAD DATA\nINFILE "+ fileName + " BADFILE "+ badName + " DISCARDFILE " + 
discardName + "\n\nAPPEND\nINTO TABLE "+ table + "\n fields terminated by \"" + separator 
+ "\" optionally enclosed by '" + optional + "'\n (" + column + ")";
```

This is assuming `fileName`, `badName`, and `discardName` include the quotes around the names.

Comment: @ chris, i tried you approach but the strings didnt break into new lines, however i was unable to input the (optional = '"')

Comment: @lee If you want to use windows notepad to view the file, you need to replace all my `\n` with `\r\n`. In more programmer friendly text editors, `\n` alone will break lines. To input optional, you have to say `optional = "\"";` The backslash tells Java that its a special character. In the case of the double quote, it means, _this quote is not actually a quote that surrounds a string, but is rather part of a string._

Answer (score 1):

Don't reinvent the wheel... the [apache commons-io library](http://commons.apache.org/io/) does all that in one line:

```
FileUtils.write(new File(controlName), content);
```

Here's the javadoc for [`FileUtils.write(File, CharSequence)`](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#write%28java.io.File,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29):

> Writes a CharSequence to a file creating the file if it does not exist

Comment: Or use Java 7 [`Files.write`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#write(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.lang.Iterable,%20java.nio.charset.Charset,%20java.nio.file.OpenOption...)) e.g. `Files.write(Paths.get(controlName), Arrays.asList(content), StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);`

Answer (score 0):

To insert a new line you need to use \n or \r\n for windows
for example

```
  discardName + "\n"  //New line here
"APPEND INTO TABLE"
```

For the double quote symbol on the other hand you need to specifically type \" around the comma:

```
"fields terminated by \"" + separator +"\""
```

which will produce this ","
and that is similar to what the optional variable needs to be

Comment: @ nick, yes it is similar but am having problems passing """ into the Optional.

Comment: have you tried making optional like either of these two:
"\""  or '\"'

Comment: String optional="\"";
        String s= " optionally enclosed by '" + optional + "'";
        System.out.println(s);
seems to be outputting this to me:
 optionally enclosed by '"'        Which if seen with spaces is ' " '

Comment: the problem is passing " into the object with " " " gives error: unclosed string literal

Comment: instead of  " " " put a  " \" "